# WSO2 GAR file WSDL to Schema dependencies

Tags: wsdl, schema, wso2

I am uploading a GAR which has WSDL and associated Schemas. The dependencies (schema imports, includes) between one schema to another is showing up fine in the "Dependencies" and "Associations" 
However the dependency from a WSDL to the Schema is not showing up for many  in the "Dependencies" or "Associations" It shows up for some schemas and not the others. I have spent several hours buy not been able to make out what could cause this issue and why it works for some and not the others. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a typo in the WSDL where the imports for the schema had "schemalocation" attribute (with a lower case "l"), it should rather have been "scehmaLocation" (with an upper case "L")

Because of this the import dependencies were not recognized. After this was fixed, they are working fine now